# insert json into mysql. json string is obtained from json.dumps

Tags: python, mysql, json

The problem is with inserting json strings into MySQL database.
In my python program I obtain json as a result of `json.dumps(d)` where d is a dictionary. Inserting code is:

```
        query = ("INSERT INTO bm_triesJsons VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"%
                 (article_id, revision_number, jsn))
        print query
        cur.execute(query)
```

It looks like the problem is quotes, there is no escape symbol in front of quotes.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the parameterized approach to values when doing a query. The driver will handle escapes:

```
query = "INSERT INTO bm_triesJsons VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
cur.execute(query, (article_id, revision_number, jsn))
```

If you want direct and manual access to the escape function MySQLdb uses, you can do it like this:

```py
c = MySQLdb.connection()
print c.escape_string('{"foo":"bar"}')
# {\"foo\":\"bar\"}
```